# Transferir valor do C# para o jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, asp

Bom, eu tenho um trabalho em `ASP.NET` aqui onde posso fazer upload de músicas pra uma pasta no computador e já tenho uma função em `C#` pra buscar o endereço do arquivo certinho.

Enfim, eu queria usar esse caminho em um player de música em `jQuery`, tem como? Porque tem a maior gambiarra com banco de dados aqui, cada música já tem registrada o caminho dela, por isso precisava de uma maneira de puxar esse caminho do C#.

Grata desde já :)

Comment: Está utilizando `MVC` ou `WebForms`?

Comment: É de grande ajuda postar o código que você está utilizando para recuperar os valores do banco no C#, e lembre de ocultar informações sigilosas que possam afetar a segurança do seu sistema.

Comment: Estou utilizando webForms... Eu até mandaria os códigos, mas a gambiarra ta bem grande, eu precisaria organizar um pouco antes de mandar, até eu estou me confundindo com o que eu fiz... A grande dúvida é saber se tem um modo de pegar resultado do C# e usar em javascript mesmo ...

Comment: Kuroi, não precisa colocar tudo, apenas o essencial para auxiliar na sua dúvida.

Answer (score 1):

Como você não mostrou o código, não sei exatamente como você está fazendo, mas se você quer chamar uma função `javascript` através do `CodeBehind` pode ser feito assim:

```
var caminhoMusica = /* seja lá como você pega */
Page.RegisterClientScriptBlock("SeuScript","<SCRIPT Language='javascript'> alert(" + caminhoMusica + "); </SCRIPT>");
```

Utilizei `alert` porque é um exemplo apenas, adapte conforme sua necessidade.

Apesar dessa solução funcionar, ela foi **descontinuada**, veja mais [aqui](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.registerclientscriptblock(v=vs.100).aspx).